# Why are my PHP class methods "not compatible with Iterator" in Visual Studio Code anymore?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am confused why I get these "problems" in Visual Studio Code when I try to implement an Iterator in PHP. I have not seen these problem messages earlier, so I wonder if the Iterator class has been changed lately? Or is anything else wrong?

See screenshot below with error message in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Here's the code in plain text as well:

```
<?php
class MyList implements Iterator {
    private $my_list = [];  // Array of items
    private $index = 0;

    // Implemented Iterator methods
    public function current() { return $this->my_list[$this->index]; }
    public function key()     { return $this->index; }
    public function next()    { $this->index++; }
    public function rewind()  { $this->index = 0; }
    public function valid()   { return $this->index < count($this->my_list); }
}
?>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the return type: `public function next(): void`?

Comment: @berend Thanks! That solved it... Didn't know that it was necessary to do that :)

Comment: @berend you should make your comment an actual answer for to be accepted and people can actual see the solution without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

Intelephense has detected your method, e.g. `MyList::next()` is not compatible with method `Iterator::next()`.

#### Solution

Add the *return type* to your methods:

```php
class MyList implements Iterator {
    private $my_list = [];  // Array of items
    private $index = 0;

    // Implemented Iterator methods
    public function current(): mixed { return $this->my_list[$this->index]; }
    public function key(): mixed     { return $this->index; }
    public function next(): void    { $this->index++; }
    public function rewind(): void  { $this->index = 0; }
    public function valid(): bool   { return $this->index < count($this->my_list); }
}
```

#### Reference

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) for the Iterator interface:

```php
 interface Iterator extends Traversable {
/* Methods */
public current(): mixed
public key(): mixed
public next(): void
public rewind(): void
public valid(): bool
}
```

Comment: Solution should include `: mixed` return types too

Comment: @Justinas correct, updated!